# C# GetOleDdSchemaTable get columns from excel when sheet name has blank spaces

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm using OleDb to query data from an Excel spreadsheet. The below code works perfectly for sheets whose names have not blank spaces (*e.g.: CustomersFromGermany*). However for sheets whose names have blank spaces, the code doesn't return any columns (*e.g. Customers From Germany*).

```
 public List<string> GetColumnNames(string filePath, string sheetName) // modify the parameter to be only the file path and the sheetName
    {

        List<string> columns = new List<string>();

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection((filePath.TrimEnd().ToLower().EndsWith("x")) ? "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'"
            : "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"))
        {
            connection.Open();


            // Attempts described below - below code snipet.


            DataTable dt = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[] { null, null, sheetName, null });

            foreach (DataRow drColumn in dt.Rows)
            {
                string s = Convert.ToString(drColumn["COLUMN_NAME"]);
                columns.Add(s);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        return columns;
    }
```

I have already tried to modify the sheetName string before calling the GetOleDbSchemaTable (below are the two ways how I tried), but none of the solutions worked.

1st attempt - insert two brackets between the name / also with brackets + single quotation marks:

```
sheetName = String.Format("[{0}$]", sheetName);

sheetName = String.Format("['{0}$']", sheetName);
```

and the 2nd attempt -

```
 if (sheetName.Contains(' '))
       sheetName = Regex.Match(sheetName, @"(?<=')(.*?)(?=\$')", RegexOptions.None).Value + "$";
```

Nothing worked so far.

Below is a screenshot of the my DataSet Visualiser when I select a sheetName whose names has blank spaces:

[image]

Comment: Note that ACE.OLEDB.12 drivers can handle .xls files perfectly, no need for the conditional in your ConnectionString like that

Comment: You need additional single quotes `sheetName = String.Format("['{0}$']", sheetName);`. So your table name should look like `['Customers From Germany$']`

Comment: I've already tried that as well and forgot to include it in the question intially. I've already updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @Afonsoalb in your sample $ comes after '

Comment: What are the results of getting the TABLE_NAME schema collection?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Thanks for pointing this out. I tried that too and no success. :( Have you tried the code? is it working for you?

Comment: @Afonsoalb it worked for me with `'Customers From Germany$'` name, i.e. without `[]`.

Comment: @ParrishHusband The table is blank. I added now a screenshot of my datatable after calling the "GetOleDbSchemeTable" and it's empty

Comment: So is the end goal to get all of the Data from an Excel sheet into a DataTable?

Comment: @ParrishHusband No, I'm storing only the column metadata in a datatable and then when I loop through this table I take only the "column_name" property that I stored previously. I'm not storing all the data from the excel sheet.

Comment: @Afonsoalb yes I understand this specific code is doing that, I'm just asking if the bigger picture is getting data from Excel with this approach.  Or is there some other reason you're getting columns?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov It worked!! I cannot add brackets, I should ONLY add single quotation marks between the sheet name. However, I should do it ONLY for names with blank spaces, it doesn't work for names with single words. Thanks. problem solved!

Comment: @ParrishHusband Oh I see your point now. The app fistly asks the users to select what columns they would like retrieve in order carry out the math operations. That's the reason why I would like to have, at this stage, only the column names.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar code and have never experienced what you're running into.  I do the table names corrections like this, assuming my sheet names are passed in as a params array:

```
var fixedTableNames = tableNames.Select(t => string.Format
                            ("[{0}{1}]", t, t.EndsWith("$")
                                ? ""
                                : "$")
                            ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving comment here.

You need to put single quotation marks around table name with spaces in it, i.e. you have to use

```
'Customers From Germany$'
```

table name in the query.